# Regex to match expression with certain number/pattern of slashes

Tags: java, regex

It's probably easiest if I just give examples...

I have input data that looks like this:

```
/foo/blah/something/this
```

And some that looks like this:

```
/foo/blah/this
```

I need a regex that will match the latter but not the former.

In other words:

- `/foo/*/this`   should match
- `/foo/*/*/this`   should **not** match

"foo" is a static value, meaning it is always "foo"  and "this" is the same.  The 'blah' and 'something' represent variables that could be anything.

So, the following strings SHOULD be matched by my regex:

```
/foo/john/jones
/foo/james/jones
/foo/steven/jones
/foo/samantha/jones
```

but the following strings should NOT match:

```
/foo/john/paul/jones
/foo/james/earl/jones
/foo/steven/james/jones
/foo/samantha/wilson/jones
```

Any help?

Comment: What kind of characters can `blah` part contain? Can they be only `a-z` characters or also `0-9` or `+`,`_`, and some others? Or maybe all characters which are not slash `/` are acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

```
^/foo/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

You can replace `[^/]+` with `[^/]*` if you want stuff like `/foo//jones` to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **regex** for this and also the `matches` method of the **string class** to match the strings:

**sample:**

```
    String[] s = {"/foo/john/jones", "/foo/james/jones", "/foo/john/paul/jones", "/foo/james/earl/jones"};
    for(String s2 : s)
        System.out.println(s2.matches("/foo/([^/]+)/jones"));
```

**result:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: Thanks - this turned out to be the most effective way for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^/\w+/\w+/\w+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lO9fR4/3)**

[image]

Thanks Pshemo for the comment. I forgot to mention that for java you need to escape backslashes and `/` doesn't need to be escaped.

So, the java regex would be:

```
^/\\w+/\\w+/\\w+$
```

By the way, a nice Pschemo observation is that if you have `/foo` as static value. You could use this regex:

```
^/foo/\\w+/\\w+$
```

Comment: In Java you don't need to escape `/`.

Comment: @Pshemo thank for point that. I'll update it... also I forgot to mention that backslashes need to be escaped. Thanks!

Comment: BTW this regex will accept also `/bar/bar/bar` not only `foo/whatever/this`. Consider changing first `\\w+` to `foo` (if I understand OP correctly these par is fixed, I am not sure about `this` parth).

Comment: @Pshemo yup, is truth. Let's add it too

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without a regex:

```
public boolean isValid(String expression) {
    if (!expression.startsWith("/foo/") {
        return false;
    }
    String[] parts = expression.split("/");
    // note: four including the empty string before the first slash
    return parts.length == 4;
}
```